# Need some settings help for doing better screenshot

Tags: just-cause-2

I would like to make some nice screenshots in Just Cause 2 and I need to remove HUD elements like minimap and pointer and maybe, if possible, change 3rd person view to 1st person.

Any idea how can it be done?

Wouldn't be better this screenshot without those elements?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a HUD transparency setting that can help, it will still be slightly visible. It won't be as good as turning it off completely but it is better than nothing.

If you are just taking the screenshot because it is nice you can always just go [here](http://www.gazopa.com/similar) and use the image above as the URL and get a very similar photo which is real and has the same colors.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't an option to turn on/off HUD elements in the game, chances are that you can't get rid of it (I don't have the game so I can't verify this). Having said that, some game engines, like UnrealEngine, are flexible in that you can change settings outside the game, by modifying some key configuration files. JC2, using Avalanche Engine 2.0, looks to be not one of them, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [first person mod](http://www.justcause2mods.com/mods/other/Gameplay/JC2FPS---THE-JC2-First-Person-Mod/), then turn the transparency down to the minimum setting.